# The Function $1-(1-1/x)^{x}$

Tags: limits, functions, logarithms, upper-lower-bounds, infinitesimals

It is well known that the limit of the function $1-(1-\frac{1}{x})^x$ is $(1-1/e)$ when $x$ goes to infinity. In addition, I know that the function is always above its limit, i.e., for every $x \geq 1$ it holds that $1-(1-\frac{1}{x})^x \geq (1-1/e)$. However, I do not know how much we can reduce from the function and still make it above the limit; hence, the following question.

What is the maximal constant $c>0$ such that there is another constant $d>1$ such that the function $f(x) = 1-(1-\frac{1}{x})^x -\frac{1}{x^c} -(1-1/e)$ satisfies $f(x) < 0$ for every $x>d$.

Comment: Note that for $0<x<1$, $f(x)$ is not real number, then $f(x)<0$ is not satisfied.

Comment: I believe there is error in problem statement because there is no upper boundary for possible values of $c$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Indeed, my intention is for asymptotically large values of $x$.

Comment: The limit is $1/e$, not $1-1/e$ and it is below this limit.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I edited it accordingly. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an entirely unoriginal derivation
of the initial asymptotics
of your expression.

You can get explicit coefficients
for the big-oh terms,
but I am too lazy
to do that here.

$\begin{array}\\
(1-1/x)^x
&=\exp(x\ln(1-1/x))\\
&=\exp(-x(1/x+1/(2x^2)+O(1/x^3)))\\
&=\exp(-1-1/(2x)+O(1/x^2))\\
&=\dfrac1{e}(\exp(-1/(2x)+O(1/x^2))\\
&=\dfrac1{e}(1-1/(2x)+O(1/x^2))\\
&=\dfrac1{e}-\dfrac1{2ex}+O(1/x^2)\\
\end{array}
$

This shows why
the terms are
below the limit.

Comment: Thank you. What about the question after my last correction?

Comment: Can you also explain your steps or give some references with more details? thanks:)

Comment: 1st step: using power expansion of $\ln(1-t)$ with $t=1/x$. 2nd step: some simplification. 3rd step: using power expansion of $\exp(t)$ with $t=-1/(2x)+O(1/x^2)$. Using this result in your modified $f(x)$ will give: $f(x)=1/(2ex)-1/x^c+O(1/x^2)$. When $c>1$ first term prevails for large $x$ and $f(x)>0$ for large $x$.